# Delete all lines that do not contain a specific word in kate

Tags: kate

I have a very large file and I want to delete all lines that do not contain the word "xyz".

How can this be done in Kate?

Comment: This task is better suited for command line. Are you really required to use kate?

Comment: @geewee no I'm not. A terminal command would be equally good

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Nix, or using Cygwin, then

```
sed -i '/xyz/!d' filename
```

will do it for you from the CLI.

The `-i` flag instructs sed to directly modify the file. In fact, the **first** thing you should do is to run

```
sed '/xyz/!d' filename | more
```

because this will leave the original file unaffected, print the corrected output to screen (hence the command more which allows you to parse the output gingerly), so that you may check that everything works as you intend. If satisfied, you may run the command with the `-i` option.

Obviously, `/xyx/` is the search pattern, and `!d` the action to perform (= do **not** delete), line by line.